# Reason for using 66 and then 70

Tags: genesis, jacob, joseph, numerology

In Genesis 46:26 (NASB)

> All the people belonging to Jacob, who came to Egypt, his direct descendants, not including the wives of Jacob’s sons, were **sixty-six** persons in all,

The next verse, Genesis 46:27 (NASB)

> and the sons of Joseph, who were born to him in Egypt, were two; all the people of the house of Jacob, who came to Egypt, were **seventy**.

What's the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is rather simple - the total family of Jacob was 70 people.

Joseph had two children + Jacob himself were obviously four people.  Therefore, we have:

(a) 66 people other than Joseph's family and Jacob + (b) four people of Joseph's family + Jacob = 70 people in total.

Note the difference in the carefully worded sentences:

(a) all the people who came to Egypt belonging to Jacob does NOT include Joseph's family who were already there & Jacob himself.  Ellicott expresses it this way:

> (26) All the souls were threescore and six.—This total is obtained by
> omitting Jacob, Joseph, and Joseph’s two sons. If we include these,
> the whole number becomes threescore and ten, as in Genesis 46:27.

Similarly for Barnes:

> All the souls that went with Jacob into Egypt, "that came out of his
> loins," were eleven sons, one daughter, fifty grandchildren, and four
> great-grandsons; in all, sixty-six. Jacob, Joseph and his two sons,
> are four; and thus, all the souls belonging to the family of Jacob
> which went into Egypt were seventy.